# Send ajax data to server on unload, with a timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I need to send some data to the server when user leaves my web app. The best way is using [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) , but the browser support is poor. I tried synchronous ajax requests, but I learned it's a bad practice the hard way - the tab will be just frozen if server doesn't return a response and there's no way to set a timeout. So I need to send the data reliably on all browsers, without a timeout in case server fails to respond fast enough.

I have implemented it already and I'm going to answer this question, but any suggestions or other solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it can be done with async XHR and 2 events: beforeunload and unload.

I tried to do it in one event, but the request won't be send until the loop finishes, even though the request was sent before the loop.

In the beforeunload handler, you send an async request and save the current time. Then in the unload handler, you put a while loop that continues if not enough time have passed or the server responded (checking readyState).
When the loop ends, the browser is free to unload the window.

Here's the code. I also enabled sending beacon instead if the browser supports it.

```
var unloadRequest = null, 
       requestStartTime = null,
       isBeaconSupported = (navigator && typeof navigator.sendBeacon === 'function');

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {

     if (isBeaconSupported) {

            unloadRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            unloadRequest.withCredentials = true;
            unloadRequest.open('POST', '/beacon', true);
            unloadRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

            requestStartTime = performance.now();
            unloadRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ test: true, _sentBy: 'XMLHttpRequest' }));

  }

  //return true;

};

window.onunload = function() {

  if (isBeaconSupported) {

    navigator.sendBeacon('/beacon', JSON.stringify({ test: true, _sentBy: 'beacon' }))

  } else if (unloadRequest) {

    //continue the loop if time is left and the request havent finished
    while (requestStartTime + 3000 > performance.now() && unloadRequest.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

      //console.log(unloadRequest.readyState);

      }

      console.log('request finished or timed out')
      console.log('it took: ' + (performance.now() - requestStartTime) + 'ms');

  }         

};
```